# Dataframe print index using pyexcelerate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pyexcelerate

How do I get to display index on my output excel sheet?
Here is my code:

```
data = [df.columns.tolist(), ] + df.values.tolist()
wb = Workbook()
wb.new_sheet("sample", data=data)
wb.save("output.xlsx")
```

How do I show index as the first column? I was able to do that using openpyxl and setting `index = True`.

Edit1: Updated code using the code below:

```
data = [myNewDF.columns.tolist()] + myNewDF.values.tolist()
data = [[index] + row for index, row in zip(myNewDF.index, data)]
```

This almost works except 1 row goes missing.Results displaying is below:

```
TestA   A   B   C   D   E 
TestB   1   1   1   1   0 
TestC   0   0   0   1   1 
TestD   0   1   1   0   1
```

the ideal results should be:

```
        A   B   C   D   E 
TestA   1   1   1   1   0 
TestB   0   0   0   1   1 
TestC   0   1   1   0   1
TestD   1   0   0   0   0
```

Input file:

```
ColumnA ColumnB
TestA   A
TestA   B
TestA   C
TestA   D
TestB   D
TestB   E
TestC   C
TestC   B
TestC   E
TestD   A
```

Edit2:Actual working modified code:

```
data = [myNewDF.columns.tolist()] + myNewDF.values.tolist()
ind =[""] + myNewDF.index.tolist())
data = [[index] + row for index, row in zip(ind, data)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe just include the index in the data?

```
df = DataFrame({'Name': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'Age': ['one', 'two', 'three']})
data = [df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist()
data = [[index] + row for index, row in zip(df.index, data)]
```